# How can I insert data from get() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert data from get() method in L_Examen_Categorie table but it says :

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
> 'L_Examen_Categorie' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (SQL: insert
> into [L_Examen_Categorie] ([id], [code], [libelle], [coefficient],
> [Note], [id_examen]) values (5, 777, 777, 3, 12, 1))"

Here is it my code

```
 $categorie = DB::table('P_Examen_Categorie as p')
            ->where('p.id_examen', '=', $request->input('id_examen'))
            ->get();
        foreach($categorie as $cat_item)
        {
            L_Examen_Categorie::insert((array)$cat_item);;
        }
```

Categorie reponse:

```
[{id: "5", code: "777", libelle: "777", coefficient: "3", Note: "12", id_examen: "1"},…]
0: {id: "5", code: "777", libelle: "777", coefficient: "3", Note: "12", id_examen: "1"}
1: {id: "7", code: "39", libelle: "39", coefficient: "3", Note: "12", id_examen: "1"}
2: {id: "9", code: "777", libelle: "39", coefficient: "3", Note: "12", id_examen: "1"}
3: {id: "10", code: "777", libelle: "777", coefficient: "1", Note: "1211", id_examen: "1"}
4: {id: "11", code: "777", libelle: "777", coefficient: "3", Note: "12", id_examen: "1"}
```

Comment: try 
`L_Examen_Categorie::insert( $categorie->toArray()); `

Comment: @Yogendra I got this error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: then you need to create a new array from $categorie data then perform the insertion in db

Comment: How can I do that ? as an axemple my data of `categorie` contains ( id,code,libelle) and in db `L_Examen_Categorie` ( id,code,libelle) the same

Comment: As you are getting Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. May be it has empty result. also try with (array)$categorie;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "toArray()" method. This method converts your collection object into an array and then inserts data.

```
$categorie = DB::table('P_Examen_Categorie as p')
->where('p.id_examen', '=', $request->input('id_examen'))
->get()->toArray();

L_Examen_Categorie::insert( $categorie);
```

But make sure the same column is available in the `L_Examen_Categorie` tables

Comment: I still get `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: @drnwork `categorie` return only one collection or more than one?

Comment: more than one (list of categories)

Comment: @drnwork Please add `$categorie` response in your question.

Comment: @drnwork As you mentioned `P_Examen_Categorie` table have `( id,code,libelle)` column then what is this `id_examen` .

`->where('p.id_examen', '=', $request->input('id_examen'))`

Comment: @drnwork in your `L_Examen_Categorie` table have same value like `Categorie reponse:`??? Or any column missing

Comment: p.id_examen from P_Examen_Categorie and  $request->input('id_examen') the id of P_Examen !! I am getting all the categories with the same id_examen ! I edited my question

Comment: @drnwork `L_Examen_Categorie ` table have same column? Or any column not there in DB?

Comment: L_Examen_Categorie  yes has the same column

Comment: @drnwork Have you cast any columns for JSON? Or As you added `Categorie response:` looks like json. Have you converted into JSON or your query throw JSON?

Comment: @drnwork Please post full error logs like developer can easily investigate

Comment: I edited my code and the error (check it plz)  adding foreach cuz I need to insert multiples categories but it seems I shouldn't insert their id in the table `L_Examen_Categorie` because it is auto increment ! is there solution to fix that ?

Comment: @drnwork Yes, I know that but if `id` is auto-increment then `duplicate` key error occurred. I don't know why `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to the string` appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Convert objects to associative array before inserting.

```
$categorie = json_decode($categorie, true);

L_Examen_Categorie::insert($categorie);
```